# PKLassoTool Custom Menu

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

Whenever you use the PKLassoTool on a set of strokes in iOS if you click on the selected region a menu will pop up as you can see here:

[image: here]

Is there a way to add more buttons to this menu?

I tried looking through the Swift docs but I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere.